# Consent for MS Graph API is denied implicitly for O365 Add-in when used via Android or IOS Device

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

We have a O365 Add-in that request for Users Calendar access so that any calendar updates are notified and sync necessary data back to our backend.

Code snippet redirects user to consent login

```
        var authServer = https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?";
        var autherizeUrl = authServer +
        "response_type=code" +                
        "&client_id=" + encodeURI(clientId) +         
        "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURI(redirectUrl) +
        "&scope=offline_access+" + encodeURI("https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.ReadWrite+")
        + encodeURI("https://outlook.office.com/User.ReadBasic.All");  
       
      this.setWindowLocation(autherizeUrl); // redirects current location to this URL
```

The consent shows once user authenticates his O365 account, this works fine in Desktop Outlook(Web & MAC) but consent page does not show up when logging in via Android or IOS Mobile and access is denied implicitly.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using a window re-direct in an Outlook app is not recommended, since the Office initialization would not be available in the login page. Plus, since the Add-ins have 'x-frame-options' set to 'deny', many providers might block it.

Please use the [Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api) for any login screens.

Comment: The redirect is done in the Office dialog itself. As we first open the dialog API to authenticate for Add-in and later redirect to MS consent page.